# Private Sub Opens Hyperlink Twice instead of Once

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a pretty simple macro, I thought would be cheeky to add a macro to a Resume where upon opening the document it also pulls up my LinkedIn. However, the macro opens the same link on two tabs, is there something I'm missing?

```
Private Sub Document_Open()

ActiveDocument.FollowHyperlink ("[My link would be here]")

End Sub
```

The Excel Version of this Macro:

```
Sub Workbookbook_Open()

ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink ("[My link would be here]")

End Sub
```

Comment: Add a message box and see if the macro is being executed twice for some reason? BTW I'm not sure it's a good idea to submit your resumè as a macro-enabled document. Knowledgeable people will *not* allow macros to run - it's. security risk.

Comment: .docm or .xlsm files will get flagged by most corporate email filters.  Also, the docs here from microsoft have examples at the bottom that work fine for me. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.followhyperlink

Comment: @CindyMeister I don't intend to actually submit it, but it's just a cheeky test of vba knowledge and trying to understand why it's occuring. Strictly educational at this point.

Comment: And have you added something like a MsgBox or Debug.Print to the Open event to see if it's firing twice?

Comment: @CindyMeister I'm still sort of new to VBA, how do I use the `Debug.Print` to identify if it's firing twice?

Comment: `Debug.Print "Anything you want as text"` in its own line of code will write the string to the VBA Editor's Immediate Window (Ctrl+G). If it prints the text twice, the macro has run twice. Or `MsgBox "Hi"` will display a message (twice, if the macro is running twice).

Comment: @CindyMeister Gotcha, looks like it's only going once, but still opening twice. I think this is something that happens on LinkedIn's side, so maybe this one is better off deleted

Comment: You could try with a different URL, just to check whether the issue is indeed LinkedIn...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197745/discussion-between-mark-s-and-cindy-meister).

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

```
ActiveDocument.FollowHyperlink _ 
 Address:="https://www.Microsoft.com", _ 
 NewWindow:=True, AddHistory:=True
```

only opens one tab.

Comment: Using this link, it opened only one tab; however with the LinkedIn link it opened too. I wonder if it's not fault of the code and just something on the HTML side